# ActiveMQ - balance number of consumers

Tags: activemq-classic, load-balancing

With ActiveMQ, when you have multiple consumers consuming messages concurrently off the same queue, is there something out of the box that helps you determine that you need to add or remove consumers based upon trends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are [Advisory Topcis](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) that can be monitored to indicate consumers/producers/connections starting/stopping and some other interesting stats...

that said, given the complexities of most systems, I generally rely on whether a given queue/process backs up over time by doing the following:

- set the `concurrentConsumers` to 1
- set the `maxConcurrentConsumers` to some multiple of the `concurrentConsumers` (start with 2)
- monitor queue size/throughpout under load and increase the `maxConcurrentConsumers` to achieve acceptable consumer throughpout

this should give you a good feel for the single vs. multi-threaded performance of your consumer process...

note - keep in mind that as you increase threads...you'll get diminished throughput returns and eventually a less stable system